# How can I sort the list in this order by popularity (most number of times)?

Tags: python, list, function

So I have a `csv` file which contains several data like this

```
1,8dac2b,ewmzr,jewelry,phone0,9759243157894736,us,69.166.231.58,vasstdc27m7nks3
2,668d39,aeqok,furniture,phone1,9759243157894736,jp,50.201.125.84,jmqlhflrzwuay9c
3,622r49,arqek,vehicle,phone2,9759544365415694736,az,53.001.135.54,weqlhrerreuert6f
4,6444t43,rrdwk,vehicle,phone9,9759543263245434353,au,54.241.234.64,weqqyqtqwrtert6f
```

and I'm tryna use this this function `def popvote(list)` to return the **most popular thing in auction** which in the example is `vehicle`

**so I want my function to return what's the most popular thing in the 4th row.. which is vehicle in this case**

This is what I have so far

```
def popvote(list):
    for x in list:
        g = list(x)
    return list.sort(g.sort)
```

However, this doesn't really work.. what should I change to make sure this works??

**Note: The answer should be returned as a set**

**Edit**: so I'm trying to return the value that is repeated most in the list based on what's indicated in (** xxxx  **) below

```
1,8dac2b,ewmzr,**jewelry**,phone0,9759243157894736,us,69.166.231.58,vasstdc27m7nks3
    2,668d39,aeqok,**furniture**,phone1,9759243157894736,jp,50.201.125.84,jmqlhflrzwuay9c
    3,622r49,arqek,**vehicle**,phone2,9759544365415694736,az,53.001.135.54,weqlhrerreuert6f
    4,6444t43,rrdwk,**vehicle**,phone9,9759543263245434353,au,54.241.234.64,weqqyqtqwrtert6f
```

So in this case, `vehicle` should be the output.

Comment: what you are trying to sort is very unclear. consider putting up a sorting criteria, field names in csv so that people can understand and help you

Comment: @kalimba I have edited based on ur request and have provided what I want the output to be

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
most_common = df[df.columns[3]].value_counts().idxmax()
```

Any questions? Down in the comments.

Comment: is there a way to not use .idxmax.. like is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Idmax just returns the most common value, but if you are desperate you can get the collections counter(1) to get the most commonly occurring item, or even write a slow manual function.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution could be (assuming you have your records as list of lists):

```
from statistics import mode

mode(list(zip(*your_csv))[3]) # item type is listed as 4th argument
```